# Python: Is there a hidden time complexity of numpy ndarray column fancy indexing slicing?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, indexing, complexity-theory

Is there some sort of hidden time cost of `numpy ndarray` column fancy indexing slicing? i.e: Selecting a set of columns from an existing `numpy ndarray` matrix.

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np

N = (3000000,500)
M = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)

mask = []
for i in range(N[1]):
    mask.append(np.random.choice([True, False, False]))
num_mask = [i for i, x in enumerate(mask) if x == True]

# 2 function calls in 0.000 seconds
%prun M[:10,num_mask]

# 2 function calls in 0.003 seconds
%prun M[:100,num_mask]

# 2 function calls in 0.014 seconds
%prun M[:1000,num_mask]

# 2 function calls in 0.099 seconds
%prun M[:10000,num_mask]

# 2 function calls in 1.520 seconds
%prun M[:100000, num_mask]

# ....? Meanwhile I am posting here (> 15 seconds)
%prun M[:1000000, num_mask]
```

I am still waiting for the last to run!

In an ideal situation, I would be able to mask all rows as follows:

`M[:, num_mask]`

Is there a more efficient way to go about this?

An interesting development is to split-apply-combine as follows:

```
# 19 function calls in 12.978 seconds
def sub_mask(M, num_mask):
    M_ = np.split(M[:1000000], len(M[:100000])/100000)
    sol_ = []
    for M in M_:
        sol_.append(M[:,num_mask])
    return np.concatenate(sol_)

%prun sol = sub_mask(M, num_mask)
```

Given the concatenation operation, mystified as to why this is more efficient though.

I am baffled. Was expecting a linear time increase to be about 15 seconds. I'm having this exact problem in a real world situation after selecting the `k` best features for a regression problem, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it's cache miss, I think if you swap  axis 0 and axis 1 it should be faster.

Comment: What happens if you apply `num_mask` to the first dimension?  i.e. selecting rows.  Or try `M=np.array(....,order='F')`.

Comment: try `take`: `np.take(M[:100000], num_mask, axis=1)`, is this faster?

Comment: Your array has 1500000000 elements.  On Windows, that's 6 gigabytes of memory, and on other operating systems (where the default `int` size is 8 bytes) it is 12 gig.  How much actual free RAM do you have before you run this test?

Comment: This definitely looks like a cache effect. Using pure advanced indexing instead of mixed basic/advanced indexing might produce a better iteration order: `M[np.ix_(np.arange(1000000), num_mask)]`.

Comment: @HYRY Wow, `4 function calls in 4.667 seconds`, thank you! (`1000000` rows)